# Using seperate items in list as input for pipe operator in R

Tags: r, loops, pipe

I have written a script which uses a list of URL's as input, and then scrapes certain information from the websites. I have done this with a for loop, but already the process time is verry long, I expect the list to get bigger over time, so I wanted to re-code my script a more efficient way. My idea was to eliminate the for loop and use pipe operators to reduce the processing time. My original (working code) is as follows;

```
imo <- c()
mmsi <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  url <- sprintf("https://www.marinevesseltraffic.com/vessels?vessel=%s&flag=&page=1&sort=lenght&direction=desc",data$NAME[i])
  page <- read_html(url)
  CSSextract1 <- html_nodes(page, '.td_imo')
  CSSextract2 <- html_nodes(page, '.td_mmsi')
  imos <- html_text(CSSextract1)[2]
  imo[i] <- imos
  mmsis <- html_text(CSSextract2)[2]
  mmsi[i] <- mmsis
}

data$IMO <- gsub("[\r \n \t]", "", imo)
data$MMSI <- gsub("[\r \n \t]", "", mmsi)
data$NAME <- gsub("\\+", " ", data$NAME)
```

I have re-written the code, trying to eliminate the for loop as follows;

```
CSSex1 <- function(page){
  CSSextract <- html_nodes(page,'.td_imo')
  return(CSSextract)
}

data$url <- sprintf("https://www.marinevesseltraffic.com/vessels?vessel=%s&flag=&page=1&sort=lenght&direction=desc",data$NAME)
data$mmsi <- data$url %>% read_html() %>% CSSex1() %>% html_text()[2]
```

However it gives me the error;

```
 Error: `x` must be a string of length 1
```

I assume, the way I coded, the list (data$url) as a whole is now taken as input, so my question is;
Is it possible, and if yes how, to take each element from data$url as a input without using a (for) loop?

[image: example of df input/output]

Comment: `lapply` is a base R function which iterates through the elements of a list, applies a function to them and returns the outputs as a list. For a tidyverse solution, you can check out `purrr::map` and its associated functions, which generally offer more predictability than base equivalents.

Comment: First, try to wrtie a reproductible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If the bottleneck is the access to the web sites, you need to parallelize your code. Try to write it with `purrr::map` as suggested. After that you can use the `furrr` package.

Comment: @CaptainHat  Thanks for the input, I have applied the map function, it works, but the process time does not improve, it's even more time consuming than using a for loop. I guess the answer from you is right, but maybe my question is just not good.. thank you for the input anyway I guess I have to figure out something else

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to set up `url` as a column of a data frame (`data`) to try:

```
mmsi_func <- function(x) {
  z <- x %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    CSSex1() %>% 
    html_text()

  z[2]
}

data <- data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(mmsi = mmsi_func(url))
```

or something along those lines.  I am not sure what the expected output is supposed to look like, but if it is a list rather than a vector, you can use this minor adjustment for a list column in the dataframe:

```
mmsi_func <- function(x) {
  z <- x %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    CSSex1() %>% 
    html_text()

  z[2]
}

data <- data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(mmsi = list(mmsi_func(url)))
```

Comment: Hi Keith, thank you for the response! You're approach works, but the process time is at least the same as with the for loop. Your answer is good, maybe my question isn't.. The desired output are the mmsi and imo values from each site, both are vectors (i've edited my post with an example of my data df) Thanks for the input anyway!